# In memory cache solution

Tags: caching, in-memory

We've a requirement to develop an in-memory cache based solution to process large amount of feed data(in tune of thousands of records). This feed data has to be replaced in cache in every 10 seconds and will be queried as well.

So,

1) is it advisable to use in-memory cache in this case, where cache will be updated in every 10 seconds?

2) If answer to above (point #1) is "Yes", what are my options for in-memory cache solution that would support "high read and high put/write"?

Comment: Question looks way too generic to generate suitable answer. What kind of answer do you expect? Advice for ready to use product of technique for optimal purging of data from queue? What kinds of queries do you plan to use? Just plain aggregate functions on full cache or on subset filtered by some parameter?

Comment: @MaximSagaydachny 

1) I need advice on using in-memory cache implementation, like ehcache etc for the requirement mentioned in question.

2) Queries will be of select in nature based on some parameters.

Comment: You could use AWS KDS->Firehose-> (analytics+ redshift). Analytics allows you to build SQL queries which take into account period of time. Also you could use VoltDB, MemSQL, Spark SQL for similar purposes. It makes sense for you to mention technologies already used in your project for people to suggest solution which fits your architecture.